# Drawing a Hodge diamond using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I've been stuck trying to draw a Hodge diamond using Tikz (they appear in the context of Kähler gometry).
I've already got the following [image]

However, I'd like to get something like this (namely, I want to add these nice Serre, Hodge and conjugation labels along with their arrows). Moreover, I'd like to add a vertical column of Betti numbers representing the sum of the diamond's rows.
[image]

**EDIT**. I got it, however I ran into another problem. I'm using MathTimePro 2 fonts, so this doesn't look exactly as intended using these fonts because of their own arrows and sizes. So, **I'm only asking for a solution that looks like the following BUT *using tikzcd for the arrows* and labels (and not things such as \longleftrightarrow)**. Here is the result, it looks perfectly fine using computer modern/AMS, so I'll left its code below, but is not as nice with MathTime, that's why I need to do the arrows with Tikz-cd so they end behaving the same despite the main font...
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, graphicx, pgfplots, tikz, tikz-cd, stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
    
    \[ \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small, column sep=tiny]
    &   &&&&h^{0,0}&&&& && b_0 \\ 
    &   &&&h^{1,0}&&h^{0,1}&&&&& b_1 \\
    &   &&h^{2,0}&&h^{1, 1}&&h^{0,2}&&&& b_2 \\ 
    &   &\reflectbox{$\ddots$} &&&\vdots &&&\ddots&&& \vdots \\
    \mathrm{Hodge}\enspace\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\longleftrightarrow$}   &   h^{n,0}& &\cdots && \underset{\textstyle\mathrm{Serre}}{  \scalebox{1.5}{$ \curvearrowleft $}  } &&\cdots&&h^{0, n}&& b_n\\ 
    &   &\ddots &&&\vdots &&&\reflectbox{$\ddots$}&&& \vdots \\
    &   &&h^{n, n-2}&&h^{n-1,n-1}&&h^{n-2,n}&& && b_{2n-2}\\ 
    &   &&&h^{n,n-1}&&h^{n-1,n}&& &&& b_{2n-1}\\ 
    &   &&&&h^{n,n}&&&&&& b_{2n} \\ 
    &   &&&&    \underset{\textstyle\mathrm{conjugation}}{\longleftrightarrow}  &&&&&&\\ 
\end{tikzcd} \]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: with same background colors?

Comment: @BlackMild without background colors at all, they just made its way into there hehe.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not helpful in the general case, but manually positioning the nodes makes things quite easy. It is possible to cheat a bit by defining a constant (i.e., a function of zero arity) to aid position/lab of elements.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{n}{0}{\def\pgfmathresult{4}}
\def\rdots{\reflectbox{$\ddots$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[x={(-1.25cm,-.75cm)},y={(1.25cm,-.75cm)}]
\foreach \i/\j/\k in {
    0/0, 0/1, 0/2, 0/n, 1/0, 2/0, n/0, n/n-2, 
    n/n-1, n/n, n-2/n, n-1/n, 1/1, n-1/n-1,
    0/3/\ddots, n/1/\ddots, 3/0/\rdots, 1/n/\rdots,
    3/1/\dots, 1/3/\dots,
    1.5/1.5/\vdots, 2.5/2.5/\vdots}
  \node at (\i, \j) {\ifx\j\k$h^{\i,\j}$\else$\k$\fi };
\node [label=below:Serre]       at (2, 2)           {$\curvearrowleft$};
\node [label=below:conjugation] at (n + .5, n + .5) {$\leftrightarrow$};
\node [label=right:Hodge]       at (-.5, n + .5)    {$\updownarrow$};
\end{scope}
\foreach \i/\j in {0/b_0, 1/b_1, 2/b_2, 
    3/\vdots, 4/b_n, 5/\vdots, 
    6/b_{2n-2}, 7/b_{2n-1}, 8/b_{2n}}
  \node[y=0.75cm] at (9, -\i) {$\j$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice code! I like this way of writing code: `\path (2,2) node{$\curvearrowleft$} node[below]{Serre};`